# Cups on slackware want to force encryption

Tags: cups

I want cups use https forced instead of clear http
I have tried

```
DefaultEncryption Never
```

In cupsd.conf,but give error and cupsd don't start
Then

```
export DefaultEncryption=Always
```

in /etc/rc.d/rc.cups but doesn't work.
How to force https?

Comment: see http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/issue-with-cups-and-https-644480/ first connection over https takes a long time.

Comment: The problem here is not long time,https works,but i want to force https only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found

Instead of

```
Listen localhost
```

must be

```
Listen https://localhost:631
```

Done!